# How do I reset an USB device without unplugging it in Linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, webcam

Every now and then there might come a need to reset a USB device, is there a way to perform the reset in software without unplugging the device itself and then pluggin it back in?

More specifically I have a webcam which gets confused when playing too much with the settings in `guvcapture` and then needs a reset to get back on track.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[usbutils](https://github.com/gregkh/usbutils) includes **usbreset**.

Run it without any arguments to see usage and a list of devices. It requires superuser access to actually reset devices.

```
Usage:
usbreset PPPP:VVVV - reset by product and vendor id
usbreset BBB/DDD   - reset by bus and device number
usbreset "Product" - reset by product name
```

This allows resetting individual devices which is an improvement over some answers that reset the entire bus. It might not resolve intermediary hub/bus issues, but it's a lot less disruptive to only reset the desired device.

Answer (score 10):

Let's say I want to reset `/dev/sdc`.

```
# udevadm info -q all /dev/sdc | grep DEVPATH
E: DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.4/2-1.4:1.0/host2/target2:0:0/2:0:0:0/block/sdc
```

I take the `2-1.4` above (yours might just be `2-1` - my device is plugged into a hub) and do:

```
# echo 2-1.4 > /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usb/unbind
# echo 2-1.4 > /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usb/bind
```

Comment: I've made a one-liner(-ish) for that:

`DEV="sdc"; USB=$(udevadm info -q all /dev/$DEV | grep DEVPATH | grep -o '/usb[1-9]*/[1-9,-]*' | cut -d'/' -f3); echo $USB > /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usb/unbind; echo $USB > /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usb/bind`

Make `DEV` the drive you want to reset, and run - it'll extract the USB port number and unbind/bind it (untested).

Answer (score 9):

You could try [Benjamin Close's `resetusb` program](http://www.clearchain.com/blog/posts/resetting-the-usb-bus-under-linux) to reset all devices — there are no binaries available, but compiling it is rather easy. Save the source code as `resetusb.c`, then run:

```
gcc -lusb resetusb.c -o resetusb
```

You can now run the tool as `resetusb`. Alternatively, @unhammer points to [Alan Stern's single-device version](http://marc.info/?l=linux-usb&m=121459435621262&w=2) (plus some [hints on how to use it](https://askubuntu.com/a/661/55386)).

Some people have also had luck [just removing and `modprobe`-ing the relevant modules](http://hack2live.blogspot.com/2008/06/ubuntu-linux-restart-usb-to-reset-stuck.html):

```
modprobe -vr ehci_hcd
modprobe -v ehci_hcd
```

(you could of course script this)

Some distributions may also have their own tools to restart the USB subsystem; [Mandrake apparently has `/etc/init.d/usb`](http://www.techimo.com/forum/applications-operating-systems/24099-how-do-i-restart-usb-linux.html#post260136).

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/645/how-do-you-reset-a-usb-device-from-the-command-line has a similar program for resetting a single usb device

Comment: `$ sudo modprobe -vr ehci_hcd` results in 
`modprobe: FATAL: Module ehci_hcd is builtin.` on kubuntu trusty.

Comment: On my laptop with debian 8, ehci_hcd gives errors. However, `rmmod ehci_pci && sleep 2 && modprobe ehci_pci` works perfectly.

Comment: The modprobe trick did the job on CentOS 4 :-( , saved my day !

Answer (score 1):

You can restart the hardware abstraction layer: sudo /etc/init.d/hal restart

Comment: i think HAL is replaced by something else in the newest version of ubuntu.. so its depend of distrib..

Comment: I seriously doubt it would have worked anyway.  HAL wasn't a low-level abstraction layer like the Windows component of the same name.

Answer (score 1):

I've created a Python script that simplifies the whole process:

Save the script below as reset_usb.py or clone [this repo](https://github.com/mcarans/resetusb/).

Usage:

```
python reset_usb.py help  # Show this help
sudo python reset_usb.py list  # List all USB devices
sudo python reset_usb.py path /dev/bus/usb/XXX/YYY  # Reset USB device using path /dev/bus/usb/XXX/YYY
sudo python reset_usb.py search "search terms"  # Search for USB device using the search terms within the search string returned by list and reset matching device
sudo python reset_usb.py listpci  # List all PCI USB devices
sudo python reset_usb.py pathpci /sys/bus/pci/drivers/.../XXXX:XX:XX.X  # Reset PCI USB device using path /sys/bus/pci/drivers/.../XXXX:XX:XX.X
sudo python reset_usb.py searchpci "search terms"  # Search for PCI USB device using the search terms within the search string returned by listpci and reset matching device
```

Script:

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
import fcntl

instructions = '''
Usage: python reset_usb.py help : Show this help
       sudo python reset_usb.py list : List all USB devices
       sudo python reset_usb.py path /dev/bus/usb/XXX/YYY : Reset USB device using path /dev/bus/usb/XXX/YYY
       sudo python reset_usb.py search "search terms" : Search for USB device using the search terms within the search string returned by list and reset matching device
       sudo python reset_usb.py listpci : List all PCI USB devices
       sudo python reset_usb.py pathpci /sys/bus/pci/drivers/.../XXXX:XX:XX.X : Reset PCI USB device using path
       sudo python reset_usb.py searchpci "search terms" : Search for PCI USB device using the search terms within the search string returned by listpci and reset matching device       
       '''


if len(sys.argv) < 2:
    print(instructions)
    sys.exit(0)

option = sys.argv[1].lower()
if 'help' in option:
    print(instructions)
    sys.exit(0)


def create_pci_list():
    pci_usb_list = list()
    try:
        lspci_out = Popen('lspci -Dvmm', shell=True, bufsize=64, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, close_fds=True).stdout.read().strip().decode('utf-8')
        pci_devices = lspci_out.split('%s%s' % (os.linesep, os.linesep))
        for pci_device in pci_devices:
            device_dict = dict()
            categories = pci_device.split(os.linesep)
            for category in categories:
                key, value = category.split('\t')
                device_dict[key[:-1]] = value.strip()
            if 'USB' not in device_dict['Class']:
                continue
            for root, dirs, files in os.walk('/sys/bus/pci/drivers/'):
                slot = device_dict['Slot']
                if slot in dirs:
                    device_dict['path'] = os.path.join(root, slot)
                    break
            pci_usb_list.append(device_dict)
    except Exception as ex:
        print('Failed to list pci devices! Error: %s' % ex)
        sys.exit(-1)
    return pci_usb_list


def create_usb_list():
    device_list = list()
    try:
        lsusb_out = Popen('lsusb -v', shell=True, bufsize=64, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, close_fds=True).stdout.read().strip().decode('utf-8')
        usb_devices = lsusb_out.split('%s%s' % (os.linesep, os.linesep))
        for device_categories in usb_devices:
            if not device_categories:
                continue
            categories = device_categories.split(os.linesep)
            device_stuff = categories[0].strip().split()
            bus = device_stuff[1]
            device = device_stuff[3][:-1]
            device_dict = {'bus': bus, 'device': device}
            device_info = ' '.join(device_stuff[6:])
            device_dict['description'] = device_info
            for category in categories:
                if not category:
                    continue
                categoryinfo = category.strip().split()
                if categoryinfo[0] == 'iManufacturer':
                    manufacturer_info = ' '.join(categoryinfo[2:])
                    device_dict['manufacturer'] = manufacturer_info
                if categoryinfo[0] == 'iProduct':
                    device_info = ' '.join(categoryinfo[2:])
                    device_dict['device'] = device_info
            path = '/dev/bus/usb/%s/%s' % (bus, device)
            device_dict['path'] = path

            device_list.append(device_dict)
    except Exception as ex:
        print('Failed to list usb devices! Error: %s' % ex)
        sys.exit(-1)
    return device_list


if 'listpci' in option:
    pci_usb_list = create_pci_list()
    for device in pci_usb_list:
        print('path=%s' % device['path'])
        print('    manufacturer=%s' % device['SVendor'])
        print('    device=%s' % device['SDevice'])
        print('    search string=%s %s' % (device['SVendor'], device['SDevice']))
    sys.exit(0)

if 'list' in option:
    usb_list = create_usb_list()
    for device in usb_list:
        print('path=%s' % device['path'])
        print('    description=%s' % device['description'])
        print('    manufacturer=%s' % device['manufacturer'])
        print('    device=%s' % device['device'])
        print('    search string=%s %s %s' % (device['description'], device['manufacturer'], device['device']))
    sys.exit(0)

if len(sys.argv) < 3:
    print(instructions)
    sys.exit(0)

option2 = sys.argv[2]

print('Resetting device: %s' % option2)


# echo -n "0000:39:00.0" | tee /sys/bus/pci/drivers/xhci_hcd/unbind;echo -n "0000:39:00.0" | tee /sys/bus/pci/drivers/xhci_hcd/bind
def reset_pci_usb_device(dev_path):
    folder, slot = os.path.split(dev_path)
    try:
        fp = open(os.path.join(folder, 'unbind'), 'wt')
        fp.write(slot)
        fp.close()
        fp = open(os.path.join(folder, 'bind'), 'wt')
        fp.write(slot)
        fp.close()
        print('Successfully reset %s' % dev_path)
        sys.exit(0)
    except Exception as ex:
        print('Failed to reset device! Error: %s' % ex)
        sys.exit(-1)


if 'pathpci' in option:
    reset_pci_usb_device(option2)


if 'searchpci' in option:
    pci_usb_list = create_pci_list()
    for device in pci_usb_list:
        text = '%s %s' % (device['SVendor'], device['SDevice'])
        if option2 in text:
            reset_pci_usb_device(device['path'])
    print('Failed to find device!')
    sys.exit(-1)


def reset_usb_device(dev_path):
    USBDEVFS_RESET = 21780
    try:
        f = open(dev_path, 'w', os.O_WRONLY)
        fcntl.ioctl(f, USBDEVFS_RESET, 0)
        print('Successfully reset %s' % dev_path)
        sys.exit(0)
    except Exception as ex:
        print('Failed to reset device! Error: %s' % ex)
        sys.exit(-1)


if 'path' in option:
    reset_usb_device(option2)


if 'search' in option:
    usb_list = create_usb_list()
    for device in usb_list:
        text = '%s %s %s' % (device['description'], device['manufacturer'], device['device'])
        if option2 in text:
            reset_usb_device(device['path'])
    print('Failed to find device!')
    sys.exit(-1)
```